# How do I make an object move horizontally?

Tags: java

I'm new to learning java and in my project, the program that I have created makes the ball move vertically. Can anyone please help me as to how can I make the ball move horizontally?
The method actionPerfomed shows the directions in which my ball moves vertically.

```
private final int B_WIDTH = 350, B_HEIGHT = 350;
private Image star;
private Timer timer;
private int x, y;

private boolean goingDown = true;   
private AudioClip bounce = 
        Applet.newAudioClip(Board4.class.getResource("bounce.wav"));;
private  AudioClip backgroundMusic = 
    Applet.newAudioClip(Board4.class.getResource("background.wav"));

public Board4() {
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(B_WIDTH, B_HEIGHT));
    setDoubleBuffered(true);

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Board4.class.getResource("ball.png"));        
    star = icon.getImage();

    x = 150;
    y = 0;        
    timer = new Timer(5, this);
    timer.start();
    backgroundMusic.loop();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(star, x, y, this);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (y < B_HEIGHT && goingDown == true) {             
        y += 2;
    } else if (y >= B_HEIGHT) {     
        bounce.play();
        goingDown = false;            
    }

    if (!goingDown) {           
        y -=2;
    } 

    if (y <= 0){
        goingDown = true;
    }
    repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: The basic process for moving the ball horizontally is the same as that of moving it vertically, only along the x axis.  As a suggestion, rather then having a `goingDown` flag, I'd use a `delta` value, which is the amount of change to be applied to the value (ie `-2` to move up). When the ball reaches it's limit, you'd simply flip the `delta`, `delta *= -1` - this just makes it simpler

Comment: Moving the ball horizontally should also be done within the same `actionPerformed` method

Comment: Am I the only one who cant stop giggling at this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea for moving horizontally is the same as moving vertically, just in a different axis.

- Apply a desired amount of change
- Check for collision
- Reverse direction as required

Having said that, you could simplify the logic but making use of a simple `delta` value, which describes the amount of change to applied to the specific axis.

For example...

```
private int xDelta = 2;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    x += xDelta;
    if (x + star.getWidth(this) >= B_WIDTH) {
        xDelta *= -1;
        x = B_WIDTH - star.getWidth(this);
        bounce.play();
    } else if (xDelta <= 0) {
        xDelta *= -1;
        x = 0;
        bounce.play();
    }

    if (y < B_HEIGHT && goingDown == true) {
        y += 2;
    } else if (y >= B_HEIGHT) {
        bounce.play();
        goingDown = false;
    }

    if (!goingDown) {
        y -= 2;
    }

    if (y <= 0) {
        goingDown = true;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Now, personally, you shouldn't be relying on `private final int B_WIDTH = 350, B_HEIGHT = 350;` as a components size may be different for any number of reasons.

Instead, you should be using `getWidth` and `getHeight` of the component, which will tell you the current size of the component.

You should also be overriding `getPreferredSize` and passing back `B_WIDTH` and `B_HEIGHT` (in a `Dimension`).  This will provide a layout hint to the parent container which is more likely to result in your component been that actual size - but there's no guarantees